# Possible to grab SSID/Network Name of same wireless router via php or js?

Tags: javascript, php, network-programming

Would anyone know if it's possible to grab the SSID/Network Name of a wireless router via php/js?

Ultimately I'd like the ability for my mobile site to know the router SSID/Network Name the user is using to access my network.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in a browser? .. definitely **not** possible ... `I'd like the ability for my mobile site to know the router SSID/Network Name the user is using` why do you need to know this private information?

Comment: because people will be connected through my network, and I need to know which AP they connected

Comment: web pages can not know this extremely sensitive information - you possibly could create a browser webextension that may be able to access this - of course "people" are not likely to install such an invasion of privacy

Comment: actually, I have 10 AP on different location or point, and I need to know which point user connected and which SSID they got

Comment: Yes. So you said. What makes you think that repeating the question will result in a different answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's totally impossible. The web browser is on a much higher level than the wireless network settings and cannot interact with it.